# Replace default_controller with different variable name in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter 2.2.0,

We are setting the default controller as 
`$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";`

I want to replace `default_controller` with some other variable name.

For example: `$route['default_url'] = "welcome";`

How can I change it? I think it is possible to replace the variable inside `core/Router.php` .But Is that a correct approach?

Comment: since you use a totally outdated Version of CI - i can't really gv you a reliable information about that. But please, never ever change the core, if you come up with this idea, you should immediately stop, beside the fact why do you even want this ? There is no rational reason to do that, and if you - for whatever reason - really need that, just create a `MY_Router` class inside your `application/core` directory and try to adjust here...

Comment: Thanks @sintakonte for the advice. I am indeed needs to show a default page for my homepage, admin panel , 404 page. So I am creating different controller for each. Any idea on that?

Comment: yea, just have a `welcome` controller that uses a switch case based on user type to display a different view. but still doesn't make sense as the default controller in such a case would be a login one. the 404 page is just a matter of replacing the default ci one and i don't really see what that has to do with routing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @Alex is right... You should put your main controller name to $route['default_controller'] and redirect to specific url with conditions.